# Shipping dates job

Tags: sql

I've a job that a need to work with dates, like this:
A ship leaves port of load only from Monday to Saturday, how can I show those dates in a field in sql?
I tried to get weekday and getdate() but I've no sucessfull

```
CASE
   WHEN PORT_ID = 333 
   THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(D, preview_Date)),103) END AS 'date of load'
```

but I need the date to always be from Monday to Saturday according to the calendar.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m6RO.jpg)

```
    CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(DATE,departure_Date))) IN (2,3,4,5) AND harbor_id = 412
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(DAY, -8, CONVERT(DATE,departure_Date)))+ ' TO ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(DAY,-4, CONVERT(DATE,departure_Date)))
        END AS 'DEADLINE' ,
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, sorry - "How can I show only Monday to Saturday in a field in SQL?" isn't easy to understand, and most of the answers I can think of (like "well, exclude sundays then!") don't really feel like they would be what yo uwant. Please show the data you have and the results you want from your query

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not english. Let's see if I can improve.
I have a report that I show the departure date for the cargo ship. In addition that I need to show the deadline that customer have to deliver the products to cargo ship. For example: The departure of ship A is 12/14/2018, the customer have to deliver products until 12/10/2018. In other words, the customer have 4 day to deliver the products. So, my question is:  Taking into consideration the  monthly calendar, how can I show the correct date? It's a daily report.

Comment: So you only want working days. If the ship departs on a Monday, the goods must be ready by the previous Tuesday (tue, wed, thu, fri is 4 days and sat and sun are not days, and ship departs on Monday). If ship departs on Wednesday, then good must be ready by previous Thursday, and if ship departs on Friday then goods must be ready by Monday of the same week?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because I have a deadline to deliver the products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear to me so I'll make some assumptions. If they are incorrect tell me in the comments, so I can change the answer.

- 1. You have a list of departure dates for ships
- 2. Customers have 4 workdays (5 normal days if a Sunday is in between) prior to the departure date to deliver goods
- 3. Goods can not be delivered on Sunday, ships do not depart on Sundays

example 1: Ship departure = 15/12/2018 (Saturday), date_of_load = 11/12/2018 (Tuesday)

example 2: Ship departure = 17/12/2018 (Monday), date_of_load = 12/12/2018 (Wednesday)

You could solve this with the query below.

It works like this: First set DATEFIRST to 1. SQL uses datefirst to determine how to number the weekdays. Now it numbers Monday as day 1.
Next use the DATEPART function to determine what day of the week the departure date is.
If departure date is a Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday (day numbers 2,3,4,5) we subtract 5 days to get the date_of_load, to account for the Sunday. Else we subtract 4.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Set monday as day 1

SELECT Ship_Departure_Date,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,Ship_Departure_Date) IN (1,2,3,4) --dw means 'day of the week'
                THEN DATEADD(DAY, -5, Ship_Departure_Date) 
                ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -4, Ship_Departure_Date) 
    END AS date_of_load
FROM ShipDepartureList
```

Even if this is not exactly the solution to your problem, I hope this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I tried to use this method but not successful, almost there. So, I uploaded the image to make clear what's happen. I've a Departure table (12/04/2018) and my deadline must be from Monday to Saturday. In other word, should show 11/26/2018 TO 01/12/2018. I need to this at several harbors. In this case is a specific harbors

Answer (score 0):

The with block just generates example data

```
WITH (
    select GetUtcDate() as shipsaildate
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +1
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +2
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +3
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +4
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +5
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +6
    Union all
    select GetUtcDate() +7
) as departs


Select
    shipsaildate,
    shipsaildate -
      case 
        when datepart(dw, shipsaildate) >= 6 then datepart(dw, shipsaildate) - 2
        else 6
      end as deadline
From departs
```

If the ship departs on mon tue wed or thu then the deadline is 6 days (4 working days) prior. If the ship departs on fri sat or sun, the deadline is 4, 5, or 6 days prior accordingly,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0801ac47b0fcd11dfa9c2ee54001fa6a

Comment: So when you said "yes, exactly" you meant "yes, but not exactly" ? Be careful what you wish for. Feel free to take this answer or the other one, and work on them/tweak them a bit to get what you want; asking a question on SO isn't necessarily marking a moment where you can hand off all responsibility for doing your work, to someone else - take the help that is offered and tweak it to match your requirements

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I didn't express myself well. My bad.
Sure, of course, i'm comming here to get ideas and work on my job. I trying to mix the solutions to fix my problem.  And i'm almost there.

Comment: If you want to give some info on what didn't work, we can help.. We can't do anything with "it didn't work" though..

Comment: Yes, I agree. Works fine with DATEPART. Thank your very much. Helps a lot.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, you should upvote it by clicking on the up arrow. There is no limit to how many different answers you can upvote

Comment: Yes, I tried but show the msg:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." In this case, the feedback for J.D

Comment: I forgot that part.. Upvoted your question though, which should help you get some more rep too

Comment: Yes, sure. Anyway, thank you for your attention and all answers.